# UIElement.TranslatePoint returns (0,0) from time to time

Tags: c#, wpf

It may return (0,0) even after Measure/Arrange. I was trying to execute it in CompositionTarget.Rendering event... and there I get (0,0) from time to time.

Is there conditions when it provides right result?

Actually I have custom control like TreeView with columns and need to know offset from the border of tree to a border of a content presenter of an item container (during layout).

Comment: And why shouldn't it be (0,0) ?

Comment: It might be, but in my case it should be equal indent 20, 40, ... and it is if I for example invoke Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.ApplicationIdle, ()=>InvalidateMeasure())...

Answer (score 1):

In my case the **Parent** of the UIElement was **null** when i call TranslatePoint, so i get the (0,0) value.
Maybe this helps someone.